# Sending Email Goes Back to Home Screen

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity

So, I have this code to create an email `Intent` so my users can send support mail.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"username@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email"));
```

With that code, it opens up a dialog where I will choose which app will I use to send email. When I press the `Back button`, it returns to `Home screen` and also if I tap to somewhere else to close the dialog. And when I choose an app, Gmail for example, it opens up Gmail (I can now send email), but when I press send it also goes back to `Home screen` and also if I press the `Back button`.

Now, my question is how to return to the previous `Activity` press I press `Back button` and if I want to cancel sending mail? Also for the dialog when I want to cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for Email, filters way better:

```
Intent feedback = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "SUBJECT"
                    + "&body=" + "BODY" + "&to="
                    + "EMAILADRESS");
            feedback.setData(data);
            startActivity(feedback);
```

This did a great job for me

Comment: It's working like what my code does. When I press `Back`, I'm still redirected to `Home` screen and I want to make it back to my app.

Comment: It must be something different than this code. Did you call finish(); somewhere?

Comment: If the code I posted also gets you to the Homescreen, then there is something wrong with the other code, maybe you should share the other code, too?

Comment: I saw the problem. My `Activity` has this code, ` android:noHistory="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: that's almost like calling finish haha :D